# tabs not showing in full screen mode in hera when using chrome

Tags: google-chrome, release-hera

Full screen mode works fine in any other app, but in Chrome the tabs are not being displayed in the new Hera update

**Update:** I realized that is also happening in other apps like the AppCenter, where the header bar is missing in full screen mode.

Comment: Used you the default theme of elementary OS?

Comment: I tried using the default theme, but it didn't solve anything

Comment: strange because I can't even maximize the window of the control panel on my computer while you yes

Comment: you need to set a shortcut in order to do that: System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Windows > Toggle Fullscreen

Comment: Okay, i understand. Apparently the F11 key toggles the applications that have this function in full screen, with the **Toggle Fullscreen** option you force all applications to put it in FullScreen, and yes indeed in Fullscreen those applications that do not have Fullscreen with F11 n 'have no menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They fix it with an update.

Thanks everybody

Answer (score 1):

There are two options to go into fullscreen mode.

## 1) Gnome keyboard shortcut

If you use <kbd>F11</kbd> you go into fullscreen mode without tabs with almost any app.

## 2) Custom (elementary OS) shortcut for Toggle Fullscreen

The other option has tabs, but in order to achieve it you have to configure a shortcut via

**System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Windows > Toggle Fullscreen mode**

[image]

Click with the mouse over Disabled (if you have not configured one already) and choose a keyboard shortcut.

Personally I use <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> because it is more intuitive for me to be like this but to achieve this you have to loose the Picture in picture mode, something usefull, which I almost never use, but of course you can choose any key combination you want.

Comment: I have a shortcut configured too. In Juno I had no issue with the full screen, but now in Hera I have this one.

Comment: I see. I have test it with Chromium, the open source project chrome relays on, it looks like with Chrome the things are different..

Answer (score 0):

It's not supposed to. Fullscreen in Chrome is supposed to mask tabs and top bar until the cursor is moved to the top of the screen, and the fact that it didn't before is a bug in and of itself.

Comment: I understand that, but chrome full screen and elementary full screen mode are two different things. In Juno I didn't have this issue.