# Does anyone know how to downgrade elementary Hera back to Juno?

Tags: release-juno, system-installation, updates, release-hera

Hera has a lot of bugs from what I can see, so I just wanna go back to Juno.

Does anyone know how to do this?

**Reasons to rollback:** Menu bar is missing in most apps when they are in full screen mode. Also, when some apps are in full screen mode, and you try to open a new one, sometimes the workspace place the new app over the one that is in full screen mode.

Normal:
[image]

Full screen:
[image]

The header bar is now missing. This is the behavior in most of the apps in Hera.

Comment: Can you list your issue with Hera?

Comment: Menu bar is missing in most apps when they are in full screen mode. Also, when some apps are in full screen mode, and you try to open a new one, sometimes the workspace place the new app over the one that is in full screen mode.

Comment: Talk to you about the elementary OS menu bar or the application. For the full screen this is normal because it will take over on the menu bar of the system and each application has its full screen mode. If you want, open another question and add one or two screenshots, maybe the problem is not very complicated to solve

Comment: @LinkPhoenix Just updated the question with some images

Comment: I just realized that your question is here https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/21607/tabs-not-showing-in-full-screen-mode-in-hera-when-using-chrome/21610#21610

Comment: Looking at your images provided here - YES, this is normal for a fullscreen mode. If you wish the bars to be kept, **use maximize, not fullscreen**. In fullscreen no matter it was Juno or Hera now, the top bar disappears and this is the way it should be. I use Loki at the moment, and the window behaviour is just like this - nothing is broken in your system because of the update, it is like this a long time ago, if you maximize the window, the bars appears, if you go fullscreen, they disapper, so going back to Juno will not help you. Just use **maximize** instead.

Comment: @Borislav In Juno the only bar that disappeared was the wingpanel, but the apps headers were still showing up. Juno Fullscreen is the same as maximize in macOS. I used fullscreen all the time in Juno, but now in Hera is different.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with rolling back to Juno (considering you take LinkPhoenix advice to reinstall Juno from scratch) is that Hera comes as an automatic update, so you wouldn't EVER be able to update anything on your system, or Hera would come along. Not sure this is what you want.

Comment: yes and i don't know how he can block the update **Juno** to **Hera**

Comment: I don't think it's possible to block the update from Juno to Hera, except by avoiding to update anything, which makes no sense.

Comment: yes I think the same thing

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using a non-standard (to elementary) GTK theme and or window controls.

Revert to stock theme/controls and see if it behaves properly.

I recently bumped up against this as well and had to change my custom css theme to work again.

HTH

Comment: No, it is because he use **Toggle Fullscreen** and this option allow fullscreen with all windows.

Answer (score 0):

It's going to be complicated, and I couldn't give you a simple answer.

If you really want to come back to JUNO I invite you to make a BackUp of your data and to re-install elementary OS Juno

I don't really like this answer because I assume that you want to do something simple but I have no other answer to give you maybe that someone will give you a better solution.